# ReactJs: componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called for component whose redux action gets dispatched last

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, chart.js

I have a component that displays four different charts:

```
class StudyingAnalytics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MonthlyAnalytics></MonthlyAnalytics>
        <WeeklyAnalytics></WeeklyAnalytics>
        <DailyAnalytics></DailyAnalytics>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`MonthlyAnalytics`, `WeeklyAnalytics`, and `DailyAnalytics` are identical components. They just display different data. So I'll only give the details of `MonthlyAnalytics`:

> MonthlyAnalytics.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getMinutesSpentStudyingPerMonth } from "../../actions/analyticsActions";
import Spinner from "../common/Spinner";
import { Row } from "reactstrap";
import MonthlyChart from "./MonthlyChart";

class MonthlyAnalytics extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const user_id = this.props.auth.user.id;
    this.props.getMinutesSpentStudyingPerMonth(user_id);
  }

  render() {
    let {
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month,
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month_loading,
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month_error,
    } = this.props.analytics;
    let minutes_spent_studying_per_month_content;
    if (minutes_spent_studying_per_month_loading) {
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month_content = <Spinner />;
    } else if (minutes_spent_studying_per_month_error) {
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month_content = (
        <p>{minutes_spent_studying_per_month_error.message}</p>
      );
    } else if (minutes_spent_studying_per_month) {
      let last_year_in_months_data = Object.keys(
        minutes_spent_studying_per_month
      )[Object.keys(minutes_spent_studying_per_month).length - 1];

      minutes_spent_studying_per_month_content = (
        <Row>
          <MonthlyChart
            selected_analytics_year={last_year_in_months_data}
          ></MonthlyChart>
        </Row>
      );
    }

    return <div>{minutes_spent_studying_per_month_content}</div>;
  }
}

MonthlyAnalytics.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  analytics: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  analytics: state.analytics,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getMinutesSpentStudyingPerMonth,
})(MonthlyAnalytics);
```

The component that displays the chart is `MonthlyChart`.

> MonthlyChart.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Row,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

class MonthlyChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      minutes_spent_studying_per_month: {},
      chartData: {},
      selectedYear: 2020,
    };
    this.onYearSelected = this.onYearSelected.bind(this);
    this.toggleYearDropDownMenu = this.toggleYearDropDownMenu.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.group("Monthly.componentWillReceiveProps() is called.");
    console.log("props: ", props);
    console.groupEnd();
    const { analytics, selected_analytics_year } = props;
    const { minutes_spent_studying_per_month } = analytics;

    if (minutes_spent_studying_per_month) {
      this.setState({
        minutes_spent_studying_per_month: minutes_spent_studying_per_month,
        selected_analytics_year: selected_analytics_year,
      });
    }
  }

  toggleYearDropDownMenu() {
    this.setState({
      isYearDropDownMenuOpen: !this.state.isYearDropDownMenuOpen,
    });
  }

  onYearSelected(e) {
    const selectedYear = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    this.setState({
      selectedYear: selectedYear,
    });
  }

  render() {
    let labels =
      this.state.minutes_spent_studying_per_month[this.state.selectedYear] ==
      undefined
        ? []
        : this.state.minutes_spent_studying_per_month[this.state.selectedYear]
            .labels;
    let data_values =
      this.state.minutes_spent_studying_per_month[this.state.selectedYear] ==
      undefined
        ? []
        : this.state.minutes_spent_studying_per_month[this.state.selectedYear]
            .data_values;

    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Minutes Spent Studying per month",
          data: data_values,
          backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  analytics: state.analytics,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(MonthlyChart);
```

In Redux debugging tool, I have noticed that the Chart whose API call gets executed last, is always the one that doesn't display the data and is the one whose componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called.
This explains the bug but doesn't explain why componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called for the component whose last redux action that fetches data gets dispatched last.

Example:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice how `DailyChart.componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't get called:
[image]
Notice how GET_MINUTES_SPENT_STUDYING_PER_DAY gets dispatched last:
[image]
And it does retrieve the daily chart data and stores it in the redux store as you see on the right.
But, DailyChart.componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called, and so no data gets displayed as you see above.

---

I just can't link all my findings together in one coherent explanation for this bug.
**NOTE 1:** This doesn't always happen for DailyChart, it happens for the other charts. But, it almost always happens for the last chart.
**NOTE 2:** I noticed if I display only one chart, this bug always happens. In other words, no data gets displayed in that chart if it's the only one displayed.

---

Bottom line is that componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called when it should always be called since the Redux code works perfectly.

So,it just doesn't make sense:

1. Why wouldn't get called for the chart whose data retrieving action gets dispatched?
2. Why doesn't it get called when I display one single chart?

Answer (score 0):

I used `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` and my problem got solved.